# JSON-LD context vs. prefixes in Jena

Tags: types, jena, prefix, json-ld

The JSON-LD spec has an [example](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#typed-values) showing a `@context` node being used to define the `@type` of a value.

In Jena, it seems a `@context` may be derived from a `PrefixMap` or specified by a `JsonLDWriteContext` (which has overloaded setters for a Java `Object` and a JSON string).

Can this example be achieved in Jena using the map approach or does it require the context object? Is there a Java `Object` that can be passed to create the `JsonLDWriteContext` in this example, or does a JSON string need to be parsed?

In other words, does Jena have any mechanism of deriving such a context without having the JSON explicitly provided?

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "modified":
    {
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/modified",
      "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime"
    }
  },
...
  "@id": "http://example.com/docs/1",
  "modified": "2010-05-29T14:17:39+02:00",
...
}
```

Comment: you may be more likely to get a detailed response form the Jena users list (if the main author of the JSON-LD writer is around).

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed set example at
https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src-examples/arq/examples/riot/ExJsonLD.java

It includes an example passing in a `JsonLdOptions` object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, any JSON-LD context including a typed value must be provided as a string. I have written a small Java class to generate the necessary JSON string, by incorporating simple prefix values as well as typed values.

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createResource;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class JsonLDContext {
    private static final String ID = "\"@id\": ";
    private static final String TYPE = "\"@type\": ";

    private final Map<String, String> cxt = new TreeMap<>();

    public JsonLDContext(){}
    public JsonLDContext(Map<String, String> prefixes) {
        putPrefixes(prefixes);
    }

    public JsonLDContext putPrefixes(Map<String, String> prefixes) {
        prefixes.forEach(this::putPrefix);
        return this;
    }

    public JsonLDContext putPrefix(String key, String value) {
        cxt.put(key.isEmpty() ? "@vocab" : key, quote(value));
        return this;
    }

    public JsonLDContext putTypedValue(String id, String type) {
        String key = createResource(id).getLocalName();
        cxt.put(key, generateJsonTypedValue(id, type));
        return this;
    }

    private static String generateJsonTypedValue(String id, String type) {
        return '{' + ID + quote(id) + ", " + TYPE + quote(type) + '}';
    }

    public String json() {
        return cxt.entrySet().stream()
                .map(entry -> quote(entry.getKey()) + ": " + entry.getValue())
                .collect(joining(", ", "{", "}"));
    }

    private static String quote(String s) {
        return '"' + s + '"';
    }
}
```

The above class is used as follows.

```java
import org.apache.jena.query.DatasetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.riot.JsonLDWriteContext;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFFormat;
import org.apache.jena.riot.WriterDatasetRIOT;

JsonLDWriteContext cxt = new JsonLDWriteContext();
cxt.setJsonLDContext(
    new JsonLDContext(/* map of prefixes */)
        .putTypedValue("http://purl.org/dc/terms/modified", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime")
        .json()
);
WriterDatasetRIOT writer = RDFDataMgr.createDatasetWriter(RDFFormat.JSONLD);
writer.write(System.out, DatasetFactory.create().asDatasetGraph(), null, null, cxt);
```